# C# WPF Print pdf multi pages per sheet

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, printing

I'm working on a C# WPF app that create pdf reports. After creating files, I need to print them out. The files created are in A7 format and stored in the same directory.

To help the forest, I want to print 4 files on one paper sheet :-)

I am able to print file per file. I've tried to set printer preference to stack 4 files on one sheet but it still print, one file per sheet.

I've searched over the Net for a solution but can't find my way.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks for your advise

Comment: please provide your current code

Comment: More than a coding issue it's a strategy problem. For the moment I use Free.spire.pdf to print a single file per sheet.

Comment: If I understand you correctly - you create single page files & want to select 4 files & print them on a single sheet of paper. To do that you would need to read each selected file into your application & create a new temporary document with the four files arranged as you want & print that. You could create a document template with four images of the correct size & [convert the pdf to image](https://code.google.com/archive/p/lib-pdf/) for printing. (I haven't used the library I gave you a link to - just giving the link as a suggestion)

Comment: I haven't fully looked at the documentation for Free.spire.pdf - but it seems to have functionality to merge multiple files into a single file - have a look at the full documentation of the library you are using.

Comment: Thanks PaulF. I was near the goal with all the tests I made last days but I need an external eye :-). So I will go on, with the free version of Spire that has a limitation of 10pages (and a watermark on the first page). I merge 10 files together and print them with printer preference to stack 4 pages in one paper sheet

Comment: The print multiple pages on one sheet feature has already been accomplished(currently for winform), the version will be released soon. BTW, free version doesn't have any red watermark, you were probably using the commercial version. Disclaimer: I'm an employee of Spire.

Answer (score -1):

you may [render the pdf files into images](http://blog.apitron.com/2013/06/convert-pdf-to-image-csharp-dotnet-sample.html)  - concatenate them and send to printer.

Or you may use the following code sample(as a sample I have used Apitron PDF Kit):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

using Apitron.PDF.Kit.FixedLayout;
using Apitron.PDF.Kit.FixedLayout.Content;

public void CombinePDFDocuments()
    {
        using (Stream stream1 = new FileStream("input1.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (Stream stream2 = new FileStream("input2.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (Stream stream3 = new FileStream("input3.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (Stream stream4 = new FileStream("input4.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (FixedDocument doc1 = new FixedDocument(stream1))
            using (FixedDocument doc2 = new FixedDocument(stream2))
            using (FixedDocument doc3 = new FixedDocument(stream3))
            using (FixedDocument doc4 = new FixedDocument(stream4))
            {
                using (FixedDocument result = new FixedDocument())
                {
                    Page page = new Page(Boundaries.A4);
                    result.Pages.Add(page);

                    // Left bottom
                    page.Content.AppendContent(doc1.Pages[0].Content);

                    // Left Top
                    page.Content.SetTranslate(0, Boundaries.A7.Height);
                    page.Content.AppendContent(doc2.Pages[0].Content);

                    // Right Top
                    page.Content.SetTranslate(Boundaries.A7.Width, 0);
                    page.Content.AppendContent(doc3.Pages[0].Content);

                    // Right Bottom
                    page.Content.SetTranslate(0, -Boundaries.A7.Height);
                    page.Content.AppendContent(doc4.Pages[0].Content);

                    using (Stream outStream = new FileStream("out.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        result.Save(outStream);
                    }                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
```